# Java 8 jar cannot locate properties file when being run by Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, properties-file, fileinputstream

**config.properties** file is located at the same path with the jar. Let's say they are both in `C:\project`

When i run the jar manually it reads the file successfully.

Unfortunately, my logger catches an error "config.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)" when my Windows 10 task scheduler tries to run the jar.

The code for accessing the file is:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
```

I don't want to hardcode the path for portability reasons. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of relative path try absolute path.

Comment: The script that launches the jar file needs to set the current directory as well.

Comment: What type of project are you using? If it's a web-app the location of the properties would have to be in a specific folder. Maybe that's it. You need to clarify that first.

Comment: It's a desktop application with swing GUI (Java SE 8)

Comment: You can bundle that properties file into jar itself

Comment: How will it be accessible then?

Comment: Something like `Classloader.getRraourceAsStream()`. You can Google read config file from class path to get exact code snippet. The disadvantage gage us that if file bundled inside kar it us not easy to edit that file.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to create a .bat file with below simple commands. Now Task Scheduler runs the batch file that points to the project's directory. It works properly without switching the relative (to absolute) path in Java code.

```
echo off
cd C:\project
java -jar application.jar arg1
```

Don't forget to add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your Environmental Variables PATH.